# Linux/ Replacing old string with macro

Tags: linux, bash

I use the next to replace string in linux:

```
sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' *.txt
```

the problem is that my new-word is macro, which defined by:

```
d=$(date +"%Y:%m:%d")
```

I try the next:

```
sed -i 's/old-word/$d/g' *.txt
```

But it put "$d" instead of the correct date.

Comment: Use double quotes, that will expand $d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes dont expand variable values, use double quotes:

```
sed -i "s/old-word/$d/g" *.txt
```

[Check the manual here.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/old-word/'$(date +"%Y:%m:%d")'/g' *.txt
```